# Monodroid application terminates without error

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a monodroid application that terminates without any notice. When it hits an exception the application just terminates. It was deployed to the device using "Start without debugging" from Visual Studio. When I run it with the debugger in visual studio I do get a break on an exception. Is this normal behaviour for the application to just terminate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sounds perfectly normal. If your application encounters an unhandled exception it will crash, terminating completely. You can take a look at the [Android Debug Log](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log) to see a log of what happened, including the stacktrace produced from any crashes of the application.

Comment: In my Application OnCreate method I have the following, but it does not get called:             AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) =>
            {
                string logFileName = LogPath + Java.IO.File.Separator + "Error.log";
                if (!File.Exists(logFileName)) File.CreateText(logFileName);
                string error = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + args.Exception.ToString();
                File.AppendAllText(logFileName, error);
            };